# Is there a way to transfer paid apps from one phone to a new one

Tags: samsung, samsung-smart-switch

The normal way to transfer apps and data from one's old phone to a new one is to use **Smart Switch**  It has never transferred paid apps before, never mind their data.

My phone's touch screen has stopped working.  Fortunately, the stylus still does.

- I need to backup my data on a Windows PC
- When I hand my phone over, I will get a loan phone.
- I need to restore my data to this phone
- When my phone is fixed, I need to repeat the process.

I am expecting that paid apps and secure apps such as banking and possibly any apps using TFA will not transfer. The last thing I want to do is to spend hours getting these apps to work twice.

**Is there any way to reliably transfer everything from my phone to Windows and then back?**

I have a **Samsung Note 20** Ultra and **Windows 10** PC.

I do have an old S9, but it has not got enough memory to receive everything (unless I don't copy much of the stuff).  I already have all my music, videos, and photos on the SD card.  But there are a lot of emails and content from WhatsApp.

Comment: afaik just login with google account that paid the app and install from play store (at least that's how it works for Textra)

Comment: I know, but there are too many of them.  And they still lose their data.

Comment: using [D2D transfer](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/backup-restore) apps will ignore app restrictions and clone app data to new device regardless of manifest settings

Comment: Is rooting an option?

Comment: @BlindSpots Sadly no, I  tried it once and then got stuck as the authors decided to not work on it any more.